# Is there any way to figure out which file is changed by chkdsk to replaced bad cluster?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery, chkdsk

I already posted similar question, but until nobody replied as solution of it. so i am trying to change the question as more detailed.

[image]

This is the last screen just before exiting chkdsk. There were bad sectors on the hard disk. In that case some corrupted data on bad sectors, I know, could be changed/removed when chkdsk is executed with /r switch cause of job related to bad clusters, so I turned it off in haste.

As you see the screenshot, chkdsk didn't leave any messages that it deleted or modified something. Still could there be any files already changed/removed? When I checked it out after the termination no found.xxx folder or chk file was found. after abort chkdsk, i moved all files to another drive, except one folder got CRC error but i got back up of this, so i throw way this failed disk after move the data.

Seems nothing to be worried. but, one thing is just unsure for me.

Not my case, but here is example message about what chkdsk stage 4 do to user files.

**Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 2813
of name $PATH1.MKV.**

It is said that there could be losses in the data recorded on the sectors marked as bad in the recovery process using /r switch. What I'd like to know is if there could be any possibility that when the job occurred it proceeded without leaving any job history on the prompt screen.

**So if that job 'Windows replaced bad clusters' was already happened but didn't leave messages on prompt until i abort chkdsk, how can i figure out which file is fixed? or can you sure no any job is not happened (yet) judge by screenshot showing?**

I think i can approach to find difference with hex codes. but i can not make bad clusters in file on purpose so could not compare.

Comment: The proper thing to do, when you are not getting answers to you question, is to improve your existing question.  Now you just have an answer that likely will never be answered, and this question.  Everything chkdsk does is reported on screen.  Some questions take longer then 24 hours before somebody who knows the answer views your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does chkdsk already could changed/removed data in "this" situation?](http://superuser.com/questions/1112975/does-chkdsk-already-could-changed-removed-data-in-this-situation)

Comment: Your screenshot does not show any bad sectors?

Comment: 1. I got to know bad sectors in the drive by GM HDD SCAN tool. and 2. ran chkdsk and aborted at that point of screenshot, cause of worried of remarking clusters job like example. i am not sure that kind of job is already happened with no message on prompt.

Comment: If you canceled before it found any bad clusters then nothing was changed.

Comment: @Velks You should delete your old question (you can do it with the links under the question) so the more pedantic folks don't get their panties in a knot from the whole duplicate thing.

Comment: @Jason C Thank you, i just deleted old question now. my apology.

Comment: @Ramhound I hope you are right, i just can't be sure about that conclusion by myself. may i know how can you sure about that? maybe i am just paranoid about this issue alone, but well...

Comment: Event viewer records what happens with chkdsk.  You never got to stage 5 though, the stage, where the recovery would happens at

Comment: @Ramhound I aborted chkdsk at that point on screenshot, log is not created in event viewer section ...anyway, your answer is "If i cancelled at the point shown on the screenshot, nothing happened (yet)." right? sorry for asking twice, but clear?

Comment: Recovery happens at stage 5 not stage 4. 1% of stage 4 != stage 5

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean? i tested on another drive and saw stage 4 replaced some bad cluster like another case that i wrote on post.
"Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ... Windows replaced bad clusters in file 2813 of name $PATH1.MKV."

and my file after replaced was hash changed. i am worried that this is already happened but didn't leave messages on prompt until i abort chkdsk.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry for my bad English, so in conclusion, my main issued drive didn't show that bad cluster replacing job on prompt as screenshot, so i think nothing happened (yet). but drive for test is showed that. i am just pointing at possibility about that chkdsk did something without leaving messges on prompt.

Comment: You should only worry about what you can verify.

Comment: @Ramhound After abort chkdsk i moved all data to new drive with TeraCopy, only one folder got a CRC error and i replaced to back up one. also i can not "verify" the all data because too many and much, they are in around 10 disks, also hope to follow your answer "If you canceled before it found any bad clusters then nothing was changed." do i understand wrong or your this opinion is changed? any help is welcome, about this situation.

Comment: The recovery stage happens at stage 5, the files to be recovered happen at stage 4, nothing was detected or recovered since you canceled the scndsk operation.

Comment: @Ramhound Alright, now i understood correctly, nothing was detected so nothing changed (yet). you just made your answer clear again. so i was just paranoid... about this issue. you woke me up in right way, thank you for your clear answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually aborted CHKDSK /r at this point, does data changed?](http://superuser.com/questions/1113984/manually-aborted-chkdsk-r-at-this-point-does-data-changed)