# Manually aborted CHKDSK /r at this point, was data changed?

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk

I ran `chkdsk /r` on drive with some bad sectors, and I manually aborted `chkdsk` at stage 4. I took this screenshot just before exiting chkdsk.

[image: interrupted CHKDSK]

1 ~ 3 stages are passed with no error messages and stage 4 only showed "looking for bad clusters in user file data..." nothing more, I aborted `chkdsk` at this point as shown in the screenshot.

So, at stage 4, since no messages were recorded on prompt yet, that means stage 4 didn't do anything to data (clusters) yet.

Am I correct?

Comment: I am sorry, it was just my mistake. i wanna show it.

Comment: @galacticninja, the duplicate isn't currently deleted.

Comment: @galacticninja - Besides the author has asked the same question several times, across multiple users, instead of just improving a single question.  But that fact is irrelevant.  The duplicate question still exists though.

Comment: @fixer1234 and Ramhound: My bad. I must have mistaken the question marked as original for another question.

Answer (score 1):

CHKDSK does not make any changes to the disk until the scanning is complete, and any changes made to the disk are specifically stated by CHKDSK after the scan is complete.

To stay on the safe side, you should rerun CHKDSK (to completion this time) as soon as possible to make sure there is nothing corrupted on the disk, and to not aggravate any corruption present in the disk.

From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730714(v=ws.11).aspx):

> Interrupting chkdsk is not recommended. However, canceling or interrupting chkdsk should not leave the volume any more corrupt than it was before chkdsk was run. Rerunning chkdsk checks and repairs any remaining corruption on the volume.

Comment: Really?  Chkdsk doesn't correct issues, and then proceed to make changes from the already-(partially-)repaired partition?  That's very interesting to know; makes Chkdsk seem safer (and more memory intensive).  Do you know of an official resource that documents this?

Comment: I confirmed chkdsk on stage 4 report errors or what kind of job is happening at "real time" like this.

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
Windows replaced bad clusters in file 2813
of name $PATH1.MKV.

or

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
Read failure with status 0xc0000185 at offset 0xb2b4000 for 0x10000 bytes.
A disk read error occurredc0000185
The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters
detected in file 73702 of name \PROGRA~1\WI7DB9~1\MIE81F~1.0_X\MRT100~1.DLL.

Comment: Those messages are happening while chkdsk is running, i have not seen those messages, think i aborted it before that can happen, chkdsk doesn't detect errors yet in this case. i got this answer from MS support engineer and other experts. are they wrong?

Comment: This kind of reliable behavior is a trace of the old DOS days. I am not sure what the exact reason for this is, though.

Comment: oldmud0, a caveat about the TechNet citation.  If you cancel chkdsk and exit gracefully, that's what the citation refers to.  If you terminate the process without exiting gracefully ("pulling the plug" on it), my understanding is that you can get corruption.  I don't believe the point about chkdsk saving changes until scanning is complete is correct.  My understanding is that it does the cleanup as it goes (and reports it as it goes).  So besides leaving stuff it didn't get to yet, terminating it externally could leave a specific repair procedure in a state it isn't intended to be left in.

Comment: So what's the difference between "canceling" and "interrupting" chkdsk?

Comment: I confirmed CHKDSK do the job at real time in 4 stage, the file hash was changed by this kind job of Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ... Windows replaced bad clusters in file 2813 of name $PATH1.MKV. i aborted when i saw this message and compared hash with back up one. CHKDSK made this file work with replacing cluster even "5 stages" are not finished.

So according to this, at least i think this is not happened by abort CHKDSK manually, in my case(screenshot). chkdsk prompt messages guarantee about data is not touched yet. is there anything wrong to judge like this?

Comment: Cancelling means ending it and interrupting means temporarily suspending it, but either one under chkdsk control.  With almost any software, if you kill it externally, things are left in whatever state they're in at that moment.  So it's a crap shoot whether that state is "ready to use" or represents corruption.

Comment: "If you canceled before it found any bad clusters then nothing was changed." "The recovery stage happens at stage 5, the files to be recovered happen at stage 4, nothing was detected or recovered since you canceled the chkdsk operation." answer from similar topic. i just tested this with another useless corrupted drive and confirmed that one file was fixed (hash is changed) as stage 4 showing message immediately, it reported immediately and immediately replaced file cluster while running.

Comment: Ofc i aborted chkdsk as canceling, not forced to shut down.

Comment: If chkdsk did its own termination, you don't have to worry.

Comment: I already changed this bad sector drive to new drive, after abort chkdsk i moved all data to new drive, only one file was not able to copy, i guess this file got bad sector, i replaced this file to back up one, and all other data are copied successfully. so old drive is already gone. i tried to figure out that could something lost or not by chkdsk ran for few minutes as screenshot. but seems to be no need to worry anymore. and tested, conclusion seems not wrong. thanks.