# How can I know if terminating chkdsk caused corruption?

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk

[I asked a similar same thing before](https://superuser.com/questions/1113984/manually-aborted-chkdsk-r-at-this-point-does-data-changed), but I came to not sure about this issue and thought I should ask a follow up question to clarify the details.

First, I ran `chkdsk /r` on drive which got some physical bad sectors. this was my mistake cause of data loss with marking bad clusters, so I canceled `chkdsk` on stage 4 (bad cluster searching in user files) and 1~3 stages are passed with no errors, in that time chkdsk was working like freezing on stage 4.

So basically chkdsk didn’t show any “Windows replaced bad clusters in file 25702” or any kind of messages on stage 4 while running, I canceled it before chkdsk show the messages.

So my guess are in two ways:

1. `chkdsk` didn’t detect any bad cluster, errors at the point when chkdsk running as screen show
2. `chkdsk` was doing some, fixing bad clusters and just couldn’t show messages for while because i canceled. in this case data is already changed.

I am pointing at possibility of 2.

This issue make me paranoid and I want to know is there any way to make sure, this drive is already gone and I moved all data to new drive after cancel `chkdsk`. I hope data is not changed but, if there is way to know `chkdsk` didn’t do anything (yet) to data as prompt screen showed, it is fine. Any advice is welcome to make conclusion.

Comment: What was the procedure you used to terminate chkdsk?  If chkdsk was in control of the termination, it would have finished whatever step it was at before stopping, so you don't have to worry.  If you stopped it externally to chkdsk, it's possible to have corruption, but you may not.  The files are now on a new drive, and they are whatever they were on the old drive.  I would think that at most, there could be only one file corrupted by stopping chkdsk.  You stopped it before checking for bad sectors.  (cont'd)

Comment: If you moved the files by cloning the drive, you could potentially have corrupted content if there were defective sectors.  If you copied the files, you probably would have gotten error messages if it couldn't read something from a bad sector.  So if you have any corrupted files, it seems like the possibilities would be limited to 0 or 1 file from stopping chkdsk, plus an unknown, but probably small, number from unreadable sectors if you cloned.  (cont'd)

Comment: However, any files that were corrupted by defective sectors were corrupted before, so you didn't make those worse, you're in the same boat you were before.  So really, your concern is the possibility of your having corrupted one file.  It probably isn't worth the huge effort that would be required to determine that, and there isn't anything you could do to fix it if you found it.

Comment: I found some facts by experiment now. when chkdsk found bad clusters in user files and replaced clusters, freeze is stop and leaving the messages promptly "Windows replaced bad clusters in file xxx" so continue the job. also as you said, files with bad clusters are uncopiable to another drive. i didn't see messages that chkdsk replaced bad clusters, so if file was corrupted with bad sectors, i could not move it to another drive. actually only one folder was uncopiable and i guess this is data on bad sectors.

Comment: So here are only 2 ways to judge. first, chkdsk strictly leaving messages when replaced bad clusters in user files, quit freeze and leaving messages immediately, i confirmed it twice. second, i can not copy files which got bad clusters. but i moved all files to another drive except one folder, this is meaning 1. if chkdsk didn't fixed bad clusters, copy was impossible. 2. if chkdsk replaced files, i could see message at real time. then i didn't lose any data in this case. it seems everything is clear now.

Comment: So is this result has problem? or not enough to be conclusion? i want to hear the opinion.

Comment: It sounds like you used copy and not clone, so you know what items are bad (because they didn't copy successfully).  If chkdsk had caused corruption, it would have been to a file that already had a problem with a bad sector (the only reason it would have started trying to move it).  So that would be in the same boat as other files with bad sectors and would be among the failed copies.  Which means you know what everything is that was corrupted.

Comment: Yes i copied all files with TeraCopy, not clone the disk. copy was successful except one folder as i said, but this is happened after stop chkdsk by myself. i was asking that chkdsk didn't replaced any bad clusters in this case because it immediately shows what was fixed at real time as i confirmed twice on prompt. (i made bad sectors in another drive for experiment this) if chkdsk didn't fixed and there was still bad sectors in other files, copy was all not successful. so it is clear now, am i wrong?

Comment: Seems my English needs more easy sentences for understanding what is your conclusion in this case now.

Comment: Your analysis of the details was pretty good.  And, BTW, the methodology you used to gather the facts was nice work.  There's one minor point about chkdsk operation you're missing but it doesn't affect the outcome.  You still came to the right conclusion.  You found that certain files didn't copy successfully, and you know what those files are.  The problems should be limited to that known set of files.  Other than that, you should be in good shape.

Comment: May i know what am i missing? "There's one minor point about chkdsk operation you're missing" if i can check this now. or you meant this as my mistake as i told before.

Comment: 1) Your conclusion is right, so you don't have to worry.  2) My brain is fried and I was just shutting down.  Let me get back to you a little later today and I'll be happy to explain that.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: @DavidPostill - This is the third time the author has asked the same question.

Comment: @Ramhound <sigh> I didn't realise it was 3 times ... was one of them deleted? I only see 2 ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - The duplicate you linked to, and the duplicate to that duplicate, might even be another that they deleted I lost track.

Comment: @Ramhound Ah. He changed his user name ... :/ Time for a mod ...

Comment: @SeiyaSouji You have now asked this identical question 4 times. Please stop doing this.

Comment: I don't remember how many times i asked, but it seems i deserve to get blamed by this post. sorry to you guys who caring that much, it never be 'duplicated' again, my last questions are incomplete and i just realized now it was my mistake to make new post. i didn't know there is meaningful way to add some information on original post. my apology.

Comment: You have also been cross-posting to https://serverfault.com. Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: Hi, again.  I see you caught some flak for the posts.  Your desire to stick with the question until you totally understand it is admirable.  Unfortunately, the site's purpose isn't always conducive to that.  In hindsight, it probably would have been better to stick with the original post and maybe ask a moderator to get you into a chat room, which is better suited for this.

Comment: OK, the missing point.  You're making assumptions about whether chkdsk could have caused corruption based on chkdsk's progress reports.  Chkdsk updates its status as it goes, reporting things **after** they're completed.  So at any point, what is displayed is old news.  Chkdsk has been doing things in the background that haven't been reported yet because they are still in progress.  If you kill chkdsk, whatever it was in the middle of doing never gets reported.  And if that results in corruption, you can't know it from the previous status update.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you for reply me back, i was aware of your point that 'final reports'. it is already past which never can change. anyway then that point still doesn't change your opinion about my conclusion? - "1) Your conclusion is right, so you don't have to worry."  "Your analysis of the details was pretty good. And, BTW, the methodology you used to gather the facts was nice work. There's one minor point about chkdsk operation you're missing but it doesn't affect the outcome. You still came to the right." i would finish this issue from your last answer for this.

Comment: Correct.  And it sounds like you completely understand it.  :-)

Comment: I would say thank you for your support and kindness even i made mistakes on the site, with helping me before blame my faults. have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

chkdsk can take a very long time, especially with today's larger capacity drives.

Here is a link to a Microsoft TechNet article describing chkdsk in some detail, and what the various arguments mean. (/r /c etc.)

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730714(v=ws.11).aspx

Running chkdsk can take hours, or even overnight or more, depending on the speed of your computer, the capacity of the drive and the rotational speed of the drive.

chkdsk does not give much feedback when it is running.

Answer (score -1):

I've done many, many chkdsk on big and small capacity HDD and SSD. As Mike Western here said, it can really take a long time. I've had HDDs which had some bad clusters and chkdsk repaired it in about an hour or so. And I've come across HDDs with no bad clusters at all but took literally the whole day to finish.

I ran once on my own laptop and it did get stuck on stage 4 for hours. I ignored it and went for class that morning and came back to no movement. Woke up next morning to see that chkdsk is done. Nothing went wrong on that particular HDD as I am still using it with no problem.

To answer your question, chkdsk MIGHT cause corruption if you prematurely cancel the process but since there was no bad cluster found by chkdsk, I personally don't think it would damage anything bad on the disk itself.