# Chk dsk stuck at 25%

Tags: laptop, fan, disk-space, chkdsk, noise

I just got my laptop repaired as its **ic** got damaged due to a faulty charger.
When i started the laptop, the fan noise was louder than it used to be before.
Quick google search told me to run a chk dsk.
I dont know much about computer knowledge so i just followed the steps. And now the chk dsk is stuck at 25% and it is running since 6 hours now.
What should i do?
Should i just let it run and wait till it finishes on its on?
Or is it safe to close the laptop? What damages will it do to the laptop if i restarted it?
Please give me a good suggestion i cannot afford to spend anymore money on this laptop.
*Edit* its been more than 15 hours and chk dsk is still stuck at 25%.
I had shifted my personal data into an external drive previously so i basically have negligible data on the laptop.
Should i just go for shutting my laptop down as i have no precious data in the laptop that could be lost?
Plus: for those asking why did i run chk dsk.
My answer is that i have no idea. As already mentioned, my query was a loud fan noise that i experienced after getting my laptop fixed. I did a google search and followed the steps of the blog that mentioned to run a chk dsk. So i did what was mentioned. I didnot know what i was doing and what was its purpose. Please help me out.

Comment: I would be inclined to leave the laptop running and plugged into AC and let it run overnight to see if CHKDSK finishes.

Comment: Your symptoms and problem description don't appear compatible.  I agree with Johns suggestion - but if it doesn't fix the problem it might be worth considering that the hard drive is stuffed.    You might want to get Crystal Disk and get the SMART data from the hard drive.

Comment: I think it possible that you have two things going on.  It is possible that they messed up the fan while inside the laptop.. "louder" could mean spinning up faster to deal with heat or it could mean that it is now placed improperly in the chassis when it was apart.  You should be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Ive upvoted the question because its well intentioned and you are new here).  You might want to provide more detail, as, as per our discussions the symptoms dont fit with the diagnosis.  Id be interested to know - What was wrong Why you think chkdsk was warranted -  What the symptoms were before it was serviced  - what the rrpair company said about the "ic" - is it a laptop or desktop - is it a hdd or ssd.

Comment: The risks of powering it off halfway through are inversely proportional to the time since your last backup.

Comment: After your wall-of-text edit, you've little option to eventually just switch it off & see what happens when you next switch it on again.

Answer (score 0):

Do not close the laptop. Leave it running. Stopping chkdsk may corrupt data  (possibly important system files) if it is fixing them while you shut the laptop down. If you **have** to shut it down, it would be less bad if you are in the last two stages (of 5)

- stage 1 verifying files
- stage 2 verifying indexes
- stage 3 verifying security descriptors
- stage 4 verifying file data
- stage 5 verifying free space

Worst case scenario would be to have it running for more than 24 hours.

Comment: Superuser etiquette is confusing af. I've seen the exact opposite advice posted on here. And I've even answered stuff in the comments only for someone else to come along and post an answer with the same advice and that got accepted and upvoted.

Comment: @John forgot to ping ya.

Comment: @Gantendo - Any support for your assertion that chkdsk can corrupt data if its shut down?  Also, how do balance this against the risk that there could be hardware (ie hdd) failure and that any time soent on chkdsk is further damaging the drive  further frustrating recovery?

Comment: Anecdotal evidence is one google search away e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/cxnsrh/shut_down_during_chkdsk_because_im_a_moron_and/ https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/4e6tn0/computer_shutdown_during_chkdsk_and_now_im/ https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/system-shutdown-during-chkdsk-scan-wont-boot-up-at/7c3a782b-943d-4654-a693-0012e40cfd31 and I've seen it happen with my own eyes. Assuming hardware failure of an HDD is rather far fetched if you've read OP's story. It happens, but not often.

Comment: @davidgo And it would seriously bad luck to have 2 unrelated computer problems like those in a row. Note that OPs story had nothing to do with HDD hardware failure so why do you think that would be likely? Chkdsk can take a long time even on a drive that has perfectly working hardware. For example on an old and/or inexpensive laptop.

Comment: `Stopping chkdsk may corrupt data` ? Only on files that are already damaged without a clear path to the clusters.  It isn't like chkdsk tries to rewrite files that aren't damaged.  Your average user can not repair what is left behind in recovered files from chkdsk.  ZERO (binary) system files can be recovered that chkdsk needed to "repair".  Sure it will leave them in a folder, but they are worthless at that point.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I just googled and I found quite a few examples of people reporting that interrupting chkdsk made things break. I do not have access to the source code, and you probably don't either.  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/check-disk-corrupted-my-files/6127614c-d04d-45ae-9d0d-8b28baa723db https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/chkdsk-interrupted-now-cant-access-drive-d/c20adccb-0d11-4c95-a75d-0363ea009099 Opinions differ if chkdsk can cause damage. Would be nice to hear from the person who wrote it. Maybe ask Tim Paterson or Dave Plummer.

Comment: @Gantendo With respect if the question - IC damage from charger? Its conceivable, but much more likely to be a cap - not that many pc repair companies would do that kind of repair.  IC repair does not lead to faster fan spinning (and which IC?) - that would be heat, software or different motherboard profile.  Going from loud fan to filesystem check is also a massive leap - especially on evidence of "Google Check".   Most of my clients cant identify a failing hard drive,  but they account for ?most? pc failures.

Comment: @davidgo Possibly the fan was knocked about during transport. Maybe dust got in it. Maybe its just a bad fan. But yeah, the fan has nothing to do with chkdsk and vice versa.

Comment: @Gantendo, [read the docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk). `Interrupting chkdsk is not recommended. However, canceling or interrupting chkdsk should not leave the volume any more corrupt than it was before chkdsk was run.`

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas See, for example, https://superuser.com/questions/1113984/manually-aborted-chkdsk-r-at-this-point-was-data-changed#comment1588046_1113990 (and below) and the links I have posted above. A google search reveals many more people who report the same problem. And I've seen it happen (albeit a long time ago).

Answer (score 0):

My chk dsk is still stuck on 25% and it is more than 15 hours now.
It doesnot explain what stage is going on so i could safely restart my laptop.
I have no precious storage on my laptop so should i just restart it anyways??

Comment: After that length of time, and given no precious data, just restart it now and see about the fan (not related to CHKDSK) and also normal operation.

Comment: I have restarted my laptop, and on the startup it said manufacturing mode activated and now i see a sign sahing "undoing changes made to your computer"